# Rectangle creation in JFrame shifting right for no discernible reason

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe

I'm trying to color a JFrame with a 2D array to create a grid, for a "map" for a school project. 
The problem is, in the (0,0) position of the frame, a random gray box appears, pushing everything to the right. It even pushes the last block to the first position of the NEXT row, which is confusing me immensely.

I took into account the fact that arrays start with the index "0", and I'm wondering why it is not drawing a black box in the (0,0) position.

Here are the two relevant classes in my code:

```
public class Floor1Components extends JComponent {
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    for (int y = 0; y < Map.floor1Schematics.length; y++) { //for every row

        for(int x = 0; x < Map.floor1Schematics[0].length; x++) {   //do something for every column
            Rectangle block = new Rectangle((x*50), (y*50), 50, 50);
            g2.draw(block);
            g2.fill(block);
            if(Map.floor1Schematics[y][x].equals("wl")) {
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            if(Map.floor1Schematics[y][x].equals("gr")) {
                g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            if(Map.floor1Schematics[y][x].equals("end")) {
                g2.setColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if(Map.floor1Schematics[y][x].equals("ch")) {
                g2.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            }
            if(Map.floor1Schematics[y][x].equals("pv")) {
                g2.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

}

```
public class Map {

public static boolean floor1 = true;
public static boolean floor2 = false;
public static boolean floor3 = false;

public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public static String floor1Schematics[][] = 
    {
{"wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","ch","gr","wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl","gr","ch","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","wl","wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl","wl","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","wl"},
{"wl","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","wl","wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl","wl","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","ch","gr","wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl","gr","ch","gr","wl"},
{"wl","gr","gr","gr","wl","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","pv","pv","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","gr","wl","gr","gr","gr","wl"},
{"wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl","wl"},

    };

public static void createFrame() {

    frame.setSize(1600,1600);
    frame.setTitle("Frame");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    //frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    //PlayerModel player = new PlayerModel();
    //frame.add(player);
    //frame.setVisible(true);
    if (floor1 && !floor2 && !floor3) {
        Floor1Components floor1 = new Floor1Components();
        frame.add(floor1);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createFrame();
}
```

}

Apologizing for the atrocity that is the 2D array, that is for coloring and detecting what block you are standing on. But I'm confused as to why everything is being pushed over to the right, and then down. I've gone over the math of the block creation and the index referral a thousand times.

Comment: Have you tried setting the color before drawing/filling the rectangles

Comment: Yes, this worked. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put

```
        g2.draw(block);
        g2.fill(block);
```

after your setcolors, if I'm not mistaken.

For the first element, you are drawing a box, then setting the color afterwards.  Let me know if that helps.  If you have the main method code, I'm willing to help further.

Comment: Oh my goodness. THANK YOU. I have been working on this bug for a week, even hardcoded around it which caused me more problems, and all because of this. Could you explain to me why this works? I don't want to make this same kind of mistake again. Thank you so much.

Comment: As far as I can tell, its kind of like this(using real-world items, for ex): You pick up a gray colored pencil by default.  If you want to draw something, it'll draw it in gray.  You need to select the right colored pencil that you want to draw with, then draw what you need.  Not too sure why it was offset, that'll require a bit more debugging with the actual code though.

Also you probably don't need g2.draw, just g2.fill.

Comment: Looks like the offset just came about from how the for loop was working from what I can see.